# Square XY grid Hexagon label from Hexagon Vertices

Tags: python, grid, voronoi

I have an array of the xy coordinates of vertices of a hexagon in python that I generated. I want to label the xy grid corresponding to the hexagon it belongs to. When plotted, the vertices look like: [Vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzD6Z.png)

I want a text file in the following format:
x y Hexagon#

I am new to Python and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Now I have the list of centroids and the corresponding Voronoi diagram. I want to label each (x,y) with its voronoi region.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by calculating the centroids of the hexagons. So instead of generating polygon vertices, I generated polygon centroids using the following function: calc_polycentroids(startx, starty, endx, endy, a) where a= side of hex formed by centroids

```
def calc_polycentroids(startx, starty, endx, endy, a):
# calculate coordinates of the hexagon points
hx=3.*a
hy=a*np.sqrt(3)

origx = startx
origy = starty

# offsets for moving along and up rows
xoffset = hx
yoffset = hy

polygons = []
counter = 0

while starty < endy:
    startx = origx
    while startx < endx:
        p1x = startx + 0.5*a
        p1y = starty 
        p2x = startx + 1.5*a
        p2y = starty 
        p3x = startx + 2.5*a
        p3y = starty 
        p4x = startx 
        p4y = starty + (a*np.sqrt(3)/2)
        p5x = startx + a
        p5y = starty + (a*np.sqrt(3)/2)
        p6x = startx + 2.*a
        p6y = starty + (a*np.sqrt(3)/2)
        p7x = startx + 3.*a
        p7y = starty + (a*np.sqrt(3)/2)
        p8x = startx + 0.5*a
        p8y = starty + (a*np.sqrt(3))
        p9x = startx + 1.5*a
        p9y = starty + (a*np.sqrt(3))
        p10x= startx + 2.5*a
        p10y= starty + (a*np.sqrt(3))
        poly = [
            (p1x, p1y),
            (p2x, p2y),
            (p3x, p3y),
            (p4x, p4y),
            (p5x, p5y),
            (p6x, p6y),
            (p7x, p7y),
            (p8x, p8y),
            (p9x, p9y),
            (p10x,p10y),
            ]
        polygons.append(poly)
        counter += 1
        startx += hx
    starty += yoffset
#Truncate points
temp1=np.array(polygons)
temp3=temp1.reshape(temp1.shape[1]*temp1.shape[0],temp1.shape[2]) 
return temp3`
```

Then I defined the x-y grid and used cKDTree to predict the nearest neighbor as the index of the centroid it's closest to.

```
polygons1=calc_polycentroids(0,0,N,N,a)
x=np.linspace(0,N,N+2);
y=np.linspace(0,N,N+2);
points=np.array(np.meshgrid(x,y)) 
test_points=np.reshape(np.array([np.ravel(points,order='F')]),((N+2)*(N+2),2))#The x-y points to iterate over
voronoi_kdtree = cKDTree(polygons1) #giving centroids of the grains

test_point_dist, test_point_regions = voronoi_kdtree.query(test_points, k=1)
#test_point_regions Now holds an array of shape (n_test, 1) 
#with the indices of the points in polygons1 closest to each of your test_points.
```

Thus if I plot a contour plot, I get the following structure: with N=128
[Hexagonal lattice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKdlk.png)